# Three.js render complete

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is there a way to tell when the object has finished rendering? I know there is a progress bar in one of the examples, but i am looking for a simple & non-convoluted example. I have looked through the loader i am using (OBJMTLLoader) and the renderer (WebGLRenderer) and i have not noticed a simple

```
renderer.complete(function(){ CODE HERE });
```

or similar for the loader(s). I want to for example throw up an alert when all objects are completely rendered.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of the loader.addEventListener('load'... section, the last line when it adds the scene, put the function after that and it will wait until render is complete before firing.

In case anyone else needs it!

Comment: I do not completely understand your text. Could you post an an example?

Answer (score 0):

**Object3D.onAfterRender : Function**

*In short I'm applying to a Mesh Object.*

```
meshCube.onAfterRender = function (){
//Here
}
```

An optional callback that is executed immediately after a 3D object is rendered. This function is called with the following parameters: renderer, scene, camera, geometry, material, group.

Please notice that this callback is only executed for renderable 3D objects. Meaning 3D objects which define their visual appearance with geometries and materials like instances of Mesh, Line, Points or Sprite. Instances of Object3D, Group or Bone are not renderable and thus this callback is not executed for such objects.

Refrence: [Threejs Object3D documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=mesh#api/en/core/Object3D.onAfterRender)