# three.js: detect when render completed

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to detect when rendering completed. I tried to use the following way,

```
scene.add( mesh );
    render();

mesh.onBeforeRender = function(renderer, scene){
...
}


mesh.onAfterRender = function(renderer, scene){
...
}
```

however, onBeforeRender/ onAfterRender were repeated and continued for my object(mesh) in my case, (maybe I use the mesh has some materials, and I use requestAnimationFrame), and I could not find the finishing the one object of render completed.

Is there any way to find the finishing render?

Similar questions are:
[THREE.js static scene, detect when webgl render is complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318854/three-js-static-scene-detect-when-webgl-render-is-complete)

[Three.js render complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16322799/three-js-render-complete)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for here. `Object3D.onAfterRender` is called after the renderable object has been shipped off to the GPU. This happens for every object that makes it into the render list, so if you have 10 meshes, and only the first one has `onAfterRender`, then three.js will keep on working through the other meshes _after_ calling your callback. Do you want to know when WebGL is done forming pixel data instead? That happens after WebGL dumps the color buffer to the canvas, which is _usually_ by the time the `WebGLRenderer.render` call returns.

Comment: I'm sorry what I want to do is not clear. 
Thank you for explanation of the process of onAfterRender, and I understand onAfterRender is not suitable. I want to know the time to finish drawing. Even after loading data and executing WebGLRenderer.render() (and repeating render()), sometimes the drawing does not finish, and I need to wait the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, drawing is *usually* complete after the call to `WebGLRenderer.render`.

Things that can make it seem like that's not the case include:

- Not all shapes are loaded (especially true if you're loading files)
- Your scene is very large and complex, requiring a lot of GPU processing

Unfortunately, there is nothing built-in that registers that the GPU has finished creating the color buffer, or even that the canvas was updated.

The best your could do--and it would be *computationally expensive*--would be to store the last frame's data, and compare it against the current frame.

```js
const buffer = new Uint8Array( canvasWidth * canvasHeight * 4 )
renderer.context.readPixels( 0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight, renderer.context.RGBA, renderer.context.UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer )
```

Now, you might *miss* collecting the pixel data, too. If the renderer clears the color buffer before you get to call `readPixels`, then your buffer may end up filled with zeroes.

Comment: Thank for your answer, and I understand it is difficult to find the finishing. I think your idea (checking pixels) is an effective way.